# Excel Formula SUMIF?

Tags: excel, formula

I’ve been trying to write a SUMIF formula but can’t get something right.
I am trying to sum two cells (example: R5,S5) if the cell (B5) with an entered date is before (less than) or equal to a date within the formula.

=SUMIF(B5,”<=“&DATE(2022,1,30),R5:S5)

Expecting that if the date in B5 was earlier or on 1/30/2022, R5 and S5 would add. If the date is after 1/30/2022, then 0

Comment: Try this:
=SUMIF(B5,”<=DATE(2022,1,30)",R5:S5)

Comment: Try `=IF(B5<=DATE(2022,1,30),SUM(R5:S5),0)`

Answer (score 0):

Check [SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) documentation, it is intended for a different purpose. You are using a single cell as the first argument, but the third argument has a different size. Per documentation of this function: **Sum_range should be the same size and shape as range**.

You can use instead:

```
=IF(A1<DATE(2022,1,30),SUM(C1:D1),0)
```

[image]